# Wso2 Emm - Agent fails after Switching from Local to GCM

Tags: wso2-iot

Hi I have a working Wso2 (2.01) setup but after switching to GCM from local when I try to enroll a new device the android agent fails with the message "Unfortunately WSO2 Agent has stopped".

ERROR{org.wso2.carbon.device.mgt.mobile.impl.android.                                 gcm.GCMService} -  Exception occurred while sending the GCM notification : "registration_ids" field cannot be empty

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Hi Dilshan thanks for the tip, however I did register with GCM and get Sender and API keys that I entered into EMM/platformconfigurations. I'm on version 2.01 - the link you sent me was for the v1.00 docs. There is no  /repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/mdm/ folder. In the latest documentation it refers to an API key and a Sender key - is the registration id one of those or something else?

Comment: Hi Steve, I also face the same issue, have you solved it? "Exception occurred while sending the GCM notification : null". I get this error message when I perform action from wso2 server.

Answer (score 1):

You need to register in GCM portal and acquire a registration id. Documentation on how to do that can be found [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM100/Android+Client+Configurations). Then paste it it /repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/mdm/config location. This is discussed [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM100/Android+Server+Configurations).

Answer (score 1):

Previous answer I have pointed to EMM 1.1.0. Please refer [this URL](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM201/Android+Platform+Configurations) for EMM 2.0.1.