# How to enable FCM Notification on Emm

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, wso2, wso2-iot

I followed the Steps of Activation.

1. Created a project on the FCM Console,
2. Copied the Api Key and past on the Emm Admin
3. Copied the Sender ID and past in the mobile agent App
4. Begin Enrollment of the Device.

The Device stays on the enrollment screen and the error is RegID not found. After Exit and restart the server I get this error

> ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.device.mgt.mobile.android.impl.gcm.GCMService} -  Exception occurred while sending the GCM notification : "registration_ids" field cannot be empty

Comment: refer this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36160687/wso2-emm-agent-fails-after-switching-from-local-to-gcm). It might help you.

Comment: been there vmLinuz  but the Documentation is for an older version of Emm things have changed completly

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the instructions given in the below link. It is the latest documentation for configuring FCM for EMM 2.2.0 
https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM220/Configuring+WSO2+EMM+with+Firebase+Cloud+Messaging

Comment: Did that it dint work that Documentation doesn't seem to even include addition of the Senders ID into the code.

Comment: Have you configured Android Platform configurations via emm web app?

Comment: Yes I have.after that i re-enrolled the device